# Cheerio : Getting a text from a list

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I am scraping a web site and using node and cheerio for that purpose.
I have the below structure

```
<li class="wrap-level-1">
                    <a class="level-2 link" href="https:mysite..." target="_blank"> Tropical Viking </a>
                </li>
```

How do I get the Tropical Viking text only ?

I am trying this

```
 $('.wrap-level-1').map((i, el) => {
      console.log('entering scrapper')
      const count = resultCount++
      console.log(count)
      //This is what I need
      const title = $(el).find('a').???
      const metadata = {
        title: title
            }
      parsedResults.push(metadata)
      console.log(metadata)
    })
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want this:

```
let parsedResults = $('.wrap-level-1').map((i, el) => {
  console.log('entering scrapper')
  const count = resultCount++
  console.log(count)
  // This is what I need
  const title = $(el).find('a').text()
  const metadata = {
    title: title
  }
  return metadata
}).get()
```

Comment: Working ! Thanks pguardiario